# Navigation redux and react native based on API call

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-redux

I am using redux and react native in my mobile application.

I want to redirect to another screen based on API response. I don't know how to do that.

I have used action, reducer and store in my application.

Can you please help me to find standard solution?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which navigation library are you using?

Comment: One way to do ti is to use the react lifecycle componentWillReceiveProps for example and depending on the nextProps redirect the user using `this.props.history`. Here is an example https://github.com/strapi/strapi/tree/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/admin/src/containers/AuthPage

Comment: @AjithPandian I am using react-navigation library.

Comment: @soupette  I am not sure how do I change screen based on my middleware API call response.

Comment: @NikhilParmar could you provide a small example of what kind a navigation you need to do according to your response?

Comment: @soupette check my reducer example. if it could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327700/react-redux-navigation-after-calling-api. Let me know if you need anything. I really don't have idea what I do now to follow proper method. I am stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to handle user navigation, for instance registering a user is to first define three actions : register, registerSuccess, registerError.

The one responsible for handling navigation will be registerSuccess that will only return a type 'REGISTER_SUCCESS'.

Then you're reducer will look like this (i'm using immutable.js https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/)

```
 const initialState = fromJS({
   submitSuccess: false,
 });

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  case REGISTER_SUCCESS:
     return state.update('submitSuccess', (v) => !v));
   default:
     return state;
```

**Then in your container** you can use `componentWillReceiveProps` to redirect your user

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if (nextProps.submitSuccess) {
     // redirect your user 
   }
 }
```

Comment: Here's a working example https://github.com/strapi/strapi-examples/tree/master/login-react

Answer (score 1):

See doc how to connect navigation to Redux -> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux

Comment: I got the article, I am just not getting how I will redirect to a screen based on response of API that I am using in middleware.

Comment: You need dispatch action that navigation will handle  

```
import { addNavigationHelpers, NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";

dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
```